How do I force the update of my list with EXTEND?
When I use extend it takes the last value from the for loop instead the dummy values that I give it inside the loop.  My goal is massage the data so that at least event on every day
    import os.path
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    import datetime

    pstart=datetime.date(2024, 3, 31)
    pfinis=datetime.date(2024, 4, 20)

    events=[
    {
    'summary'         : 'Real Event1',
    'creator'         : {'email': None, 'self': None},
    'organizer'       : {'email': None, 'self': None},
    'start'           : {'dateTime': "2024-03-31"},
    'end'             : {'date': None},
    }
    ,
    {
    'summary': 'Real Event2',
    'creator': {'email': None, 'self': None},
    'organizer': {'email': None, 'self': None},
    'start': {'dateTime': "2024-04-05"},
    'end': {'date': None},
    }
    ]

    gcal_dummy=[
    {
    'summary'         : 'DUMMYDATA',
    'creator'         : {'email': None, 'self': None},
    'organizer'       : {'email': None, 'self': None},
    'start'           : {'dateTime': "1960-01-01"},
    'end'             : {'date': None},
    }]
    
    #massage the list by adding a day within the 
    #first add the whole range with dummy dates
    diff=pfinis-pstart
    diff=diff.days
    dummy=pstart
    for i in range(diff): 
        dummy += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        print("dummy=",dummy)
        events.extend(gcal_dummy)
        events[-1]["start"]["date"]=dummy
        print("*****",i,events[-1])
    print("----------")    

    #why is the last value which is 2024apr20 being repeated within all the extends?
    x=-1
    for event in events:
        x=x+1
        print(x,"MAS:", event['start'],event['summary'])




I see the new date t
here's example of the print results inside the for loop


15 {'summary': 'DUMMYDATA', 'creator': {'email': None, 'self': None}, 'organizer': {'email': None, 'self': None}, 'start': {'dateTime': '1960-01-01', 'date': datetime.date(2024, 4, 16)}, 'end': {'date': None}}
dummy= 2024-04-17



13 MAS: {'dateTime': '1960-01-01', 'date': datetime.date(2024, 4, 20)} DUMMYDATA
14 MAS: {'dateTime': '1960-01-01', 'date': datetime.date(2024, 4, 20)} DUMMYDATA
15 MAS: {'dateTime': '1960-01-01', 'date': datetime.date(2024, 4, 20)} DUMMYDATA
16 MAS: {'dateTime': '1960-01-01', 'date': datetime.date(2024, 4, 20)} DUMMYDATA




Right after your last print line, add this: print(f"Memory ID of object {x} is {id(event)}"). Then go read about assignment vs. shallow/deep copies of objects.

Right.  At the end of your loop, your list contains 20 references to the exact same object.  Change one, change them all.

To elaborate on what Dan and Tim Roberts have said, you want to change the events.extend(gcal_dummy) line to say events.extend(copy.deepcopy(gcal_dummy)).
